# IFrame vs Script.. which is better for calling a game levels?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am creating HTML5 game with 40 level, I created the Main Menus in a Separated HTML file, and I will create each level in a separated file, 
the level user select will load at run-time..

is it better to use an Iframe to load the selected level as html, or to include the selected level as js file..
Game performance is the main interest..

Thank You..

Comment: performance won't make much difference. But avoid Iframes at all cost, I'd say.

Comment: And there are no common functions between all those levels?

Comment: of course there are some common functions.. @Kaiido

Comment: Then the answer is obvious

Comment: explain more please.. @Kaiido

Comment: Well, why would you declare 40 times same functions, or make 40 calls to the same main script or redeclare 40 times the same elements or add the dangerous step to talk to main page?

Comment: In all ways, I can move these common functions to another script and call it once from the main page, right? @Kaiido

Comment: Unless your stages are completely differents (mini-games), as @Kaiido suggests it makes more sense, for maaaaany reasons, to have one single data-driven script.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call asynchronously using JavaScript, but for some reasons:

In my opinion, if the frame that you'll embed will not interact with parent frame it's okay. But not to mention some browsers / security applications may block iframes. That's why I'd always go for "script" in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid iframe for security reason (clickjack attack), in this case 
   performance shouldn't have much difference.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested, you can use JQuery to reference that URL:

$.get('http://foo.com/yourContent.html');

Comment: Please use proper formatting for your code snippet.